# c++ defining class in another, not enclosing, namespace via "using"

Tags: c++, class, namespaces, definition

g++, icc and clang accept following code :

```
namespace ns { struct A ; }
namespace ns1 // note : not enclosing namespace
{ 
    using namespace ns ;
    struct A { } ;
}
```

is this a valid code due to standard.?

---

> [namespace.**qual**]#7:
>    ... However, in such namespace member declarations, the
>   nested-name-specifier may rely on using-directives to implicitly
>   provide the **initial part** of the nested-name-specifier.

as noted in related [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25177404/4625005),

> you may omit the initial part of the nested-name-specifier, but not any intermediate part.

(from where i got that it can/must be done in enclosing namespace i do not remember.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code complies, but might not do what you expected.

```
namespace ns 
{ 
    struct A ;      // declaration of ns::A
}
namespace ns1
{ 
    using namespace ns ;
    struct A { } ;  // definition of ns1::A, which has nothing to do with ns::A
}
```

Note any declarations inside the namespace become the members of that namespace, so `ns::A` and `ns1::A` are two irrelevant `struct`s.

Answer (score 2):

The code compiles well but I agree with @songyuangyao's answer, also beware of shadowing.

For instance,

```
namespace ns 
{ 
   struct A ;
  /* Calling A inside this scope will definitely refer to struct A defined in
     this(ns) namespace, and everytime you want to access struct A of ns1, 
     you need to call it via ns1::A otherwise it will refer to ns::A (which is defined in 
     this namespace.
  */
}    
namespace ns1
{ 
   using namespace ns ;
   struct A { } ;
}
```